# What does "read_strt" meaning here?

Tags: vbscript

What does this vbscript code mean?

```
<%=read_strt(objRS, "ccnumber", "")%>
```

I want to know whats the meaning or used of `read_strt` on the code?

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like someone is storing Credit Card numbers in the database, not good when there are Payment Gateway services that take that responsibility away from you and the strict regulations that go along with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement writes the return value of a call to the function "read_strt" to the HTML output stream. The function seems to **read** the value of a field/column in the current row of a database query (recordset), convert its **type** to **String** and/or **test** it against 'bad' (e.g. Null) values; in that case the default value ("", empty string) is returned.